# How to declare a Dictionary in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a simple way to declare a dictionary or to convert a SQL result (Lookup activity) to a dictionary?

Example:

SQL Lookup response:

```
{
 "Id": "12313ased",
 "Name": "john"
},
{
 "Id": "123dsada",
 "Name": "doe"
}
```

What I want:
`Dict("12313ased": "john", "123dsada", "doe")` (or whatever format Azure Data Factory works best for this).

Comment: As far as I know, Data factory doesn't have the concept of a Dictionary. Can you clarify what you want to accomplish? Your Lookup value is already an array, are you trying to convert that to a single string? How are you planning to consume the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to declare a dictionary parameter in Azure Data Factory (ADF) / Synapse Pipelines.  Declare an **Object** parameter and populate it like this:

[image: Parameter definition]

The dictionary itself takes the form:

```
{
  "values": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

You can then fetch values out by key using expressions like:

```
@pipeline().parameters.pDictionary.values['key1']
```

or more dynamically, eg using another parameter:

```
@pipeline().parameters.pDictionary.values[pipeline().parameters.pKeyToCheck]
```

or using a variable:

```
@pipeline().parameters.pDictionary.values[variables('varKeyToCheck')]
```

Variables in ADF do not support the Object type directly.  You can however loop through the output from things like Lookups with the [For Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) activity.