# Azure Data Factory convert Hex to string

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to convert Hex to readable string in data factory.

**Note:** in this case i am not supposed to use data flow.

```
Input file:

    col_a
    ------
    0x737461636b6f766572666c6f77

    
 Output:
    
    After converting I need to capture this value in a variable:
    
        ?stackoverflow
```

**Explanation:** The value of 0x737461636b6f766572666c6f77 HEX is equals to ?stackoverflow string after conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) built-in [expressions and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) do not currently support conversion from hex to string (happy to be corrected) but you do have a couple of options:

1. if you have some nearby SQL compute (either Azure SQL DB, Azure Synapse Analytics, Managed Instance etc) you could call out to them via a `Lookup` activity, eg

   ```
   SELECT CAST( 0x737461636b6f766572666c6f77 AS VARCHAR(100) );
   ```

You could construct this statement as an expression like this:

```
@concat('SELECT CAST( ', variables('varInput'),' AS VARCHAR(100) );')
```

A working example:

[image]

2. you could also use a notebook, eg Databricks or Synapse Notebook.  Here's a simple example in Scala:

[image]

NB I did get this to work using a purely ADF expression based technique, a For Each activity, Append variable and this [dictionary technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247134/how-to-declare-a-dictionary-in-azure-data-factory) but it took 30 seconds to run which I think is terrible.  I also got a method with built-in function `decodeUriComponent` to work, given `@decodeUriComponent('%6b')` is 'k' with similar runtimes.  You still have to loop through the string in chunks of two characters sequentially and it takes ages.  I also looked for an external public REST API (you could call with the Web activity) which did this conversion but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the **Unhex** conversion function is not available at the pipeline level to convert the Hex value to a string.

You could use derived column transformation in data flow or you can call the Azure function for converting the value.