# How to create a key-value map with pipeline expression (not data flow expression) in Azure Data Factory (Synapse Studio)

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have two arrays that have respectively contain keys and values:
**array 1** `["key1", "key2", "key3"]` and **array 2** `["value1", "value2", "value3"]`

With ADF data flow expression, I can construct a key-value map with these two arrays using `keyValues` function:

```
keyValues(["key1", "key2", "key3"],["value1", "value2", "value3"])
```

And this will return a result like this:

```
["key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2", "key3" -> "value3"]
```

I want to construct the same key-value map within a pipeline, not data flow, but the `keyValues` function is not available in pipeline expression. How can I construct a key-value map with pipeline expression on Azure Data Factory / Synapse Studio?

Comment: Similar concept, close enough?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69286004/1527504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to create a key value pair using pipeline expression builder as in dataflows. The following is one to build the required key value pairs in ADF pipelines:

- I have taken 2 parameters with the following values:

[image]

- Let's say `req` is the variable in which we would like to store our final key value pair. I have initialized it with the value `{}`

[image]

- In `for each`, I have used items value as `@range(0,length(pipeline().parameters.keys))` to generate index.

[image]

- Now, I have taken a variable called `temp` to apply union on the current value of `req` and the dynamically built key-value pair for current iteration.

```
@string(union(json(variables('req')),json(concat('{"',pipeline().parameters.keys[item()],'":"',pipeline().parameters.values[item()],'"}'))))
```

[image]

- Finally, I am updating the value of `req` variable for each iteration with the current `temp` value i.e., `@variables('temp')`:

[image]

- After running the pipeline, it would generate the following output in req variable:
  [image]

**NOTE:** Object type variables are not supported in ADF pipelines. Whenever you want to use this object (stored as string), you can convert it to an object type using `@json()` function

Comment: Tried it out and got the map, thank you very much!