# Create a dictionary object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to build a dictionary in Azure Data Factory using the object data type by converting the output of a Lookup activity and running a FOR EACH loop to build it. The append activity works only for arrays. I am wondering if this is even possible.

[image]

[image]

**From Lookup output:**

```
"Value":[
        {
            "name": "key1",
            "value": "value1"
        },
        {
            "name": "key2",
            "value": "value2"
        }
        ]
```

**I need to create the following object to use it as a dictionary:**

```
{
  "values": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247134/how-to-declare-a-dictionary-in-azure-data-factory) answer for your question?

Comment: @AmareswarapuBhavani no, I have seen that post, they build it manually which is not the case for me

Comment: This can be achieved using mapping dataflow

Comment: @AnnuKumari-MSFT Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps. Store the lookup output in json file in datalake.

1. Point to the same in source transformation in dataflow.
2. Add pivot transformation and select 'name' as the pivot key and `first(value)` as the pivot column expression .
3. Click on map drifted option in data preview tab of pivot transformation.
4. Use derived column transformation to create a column called 'values' and create sub columns underneath with expression as `@(key1=key1,      key2=key2)`
5. Then , use select transformation to remove the pivoted columns 'key1' and 'key2' and only keep 'values' column.
6. Use Sink transformation and load the data to a json file.

[image]

Comment: is there an easier way to do this? the original json file is practically the result of running a query on a SQL table using a stored procedure activity. I thought there should be a whole lot simpler way to build such a dictionary